# Firebase Performance crashes the app on the first call to NSURLSession

Tags: ios, firebase-performance

I have just added Firebase Performance to my which is mainly Obj-C and has Firebase (Core + Analytics + Messaging + Config) I read in the docs that:

> Performance Monitoring does not support network requests made using
>   the NSURLConnection class.

However what's not expected is that the app crashes on the first call of NSURL*
e.g. I'm using a lib called "Harpy" which checks for new version of the app in the AppStore and it crashes here:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession]; // <--- Crashes here
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session
      dataTaskWithRequest:request
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if ([data length] > 0 && !error) { // Success
                [self parseResults:data];
            }
        }
];
```

I can't really see any useful exception however the thread starts with:

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.google.FPRNSURLSessionInstrumentation (serial)
```

Comment: I wrote the functionality that you're using (thanks for using it)! It sounds very odd to me--would it be possible to create an Xcode project that demonstrates the issue with the minimal amount of code? If you take the time do that, I'd be greatly appreciative and will definitely fix it! Also, you can join me (and other authors of the SDK) in the performance channel of the firebase slack at https://firebase.community/

Comment: is it possible that [self parseResults:] is throwing an exception?

Comment: @mike_haney just this line crashes the app, 
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
I disabled this, then I found that the next usage of NSURLSession crashes the app as well.

Comment: I'll try to create a new project to reproduce and see what will happen, will let you know and post on Slack as I joined the channel already

Comment: very weird. thanks for attempting to make the project!

Comment: So I found the issue, Firebase Performance doesn't work with Crittercism enabled, as Crittercism monitors network as well so I suppose they're conflicting at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So issue above was not directly related to Firebase itself, but actually to a conflict between Firebase Performance and Crittercism, the solution was to disable Crittercism's monitoring for NSURLSession as follows:

```
CrittercismConfig *config = [CrittercismConfig defaultConfig];
config.monitorNSURLSession = false;
[Crittercism enableWithAppID:settingsManager.crittericismKey andConfig:config];
[Crittercism setValue:[NSLocale preferredLanguages].firstObject forKey:@"deviceLanguage"];
```