# Firebase Performance crashes on first URLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-performance

I added Firebase Performance to iOS project however it crashes with the first creation of URLSessionDataTask.

I am using custom operation class to handle server requests. But I do not see how it could be relevant.

Crash happens here:

```
sessionDataTask = urlSession?.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,
                                       completionHandler: { [weak self] (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
                                       self?.didFinishDataTaskWith(data: data, response: response, error: error)
})
```

And I cannot see anything else that could help to track the issue:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii71T.png)

Closest thing I found on the internet is following question but I am not using Crittercism or anything similar:

[Firebase Performance crashes the app on the first call to NSURLSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266241/firebase-performance-crashes-the-app-on-the-first-call-to-nsurlsession)

Comment: If you have a bug report, file that with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support